# Is there a XL C builtin for LXVD2X prior to 13.1.4?

Tags: c, built-in, xlc, altivec

I'm working from C/C++ using built-ins. I need the `lvd2x` instruction to load unaligned data into a VMX register. It looks like `lvd2x` is available on Power7 and Power8 processors.

GCC provides `vec_vsx_ld` built-in to perform the task. According to [IBM XL C/C++ for Linux, V13.1.5](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27048883&aid=3), Chapter 4, Enhancements added in Version 13.1.4:

> New built-in functions
>
> The following GCC vector built-in functions are supported:
>
> - vec_vsx_ld
> - ...

The code is guarded for XL C, so I don't need GCC's built-ins. The problem is, I can't find XL C's built-in for `lvd2x`:

```
#if defined(__xlc__) || defined(__xlC__)
    uint8x16_p8 block = vec_vsx_ld(0, t);
#else
    uint64x2_p8 block = (uint64x2_p8)vec_vsx_ld(0, t);
#endif
```

The GCC compile farm provides AIX with XL C v13.1.3 (5725-C72, 5765-J07). Is there a XL C builtin for LXVD2X prior to 13.1.4? If there is a built-in, then what is it? If not, then how do we gain access to the instruction?

(I'm trying to avoid ASM and inline ASM. I don't know enough about the processor to write it. I've also had a fairly unpleasant experience, and I don't want to amplify the pain by trying to use asm).

Comment: Q: How do we gain access to the instruction (using GCC)?  A: Inline assembly is an obvious choice ;)  Why not at least *TRY* it?  PS: Your architecture is Power PC, correct?

Comment: @paulsm4 - GCC is fine. I need it for IBM's XL C compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The portable function that should be implemented by both GCC and XL is vec_xl.  It's part of the PPC64-LE ABI.

The older functions that XLC supported are [vec_xld2](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSXVZZ_13.1.2/com.ibm.xlcpp1312.lelinux.doc/compiler_ref/vec_xld2.html) (for loading a vector containing 8-byte elements) and vec_xlw4 (for loading a vector containing 4-byte elements.)

Note that if you require big-endian vector element order, you should use vec_xl_be, or compile with -qaltivec=be.

Comment: Thank you very much. `vec_xl` and `vec_xl_be` should be the last thing I need. We are almost there...